# I am installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 from a DVD and I can't choose where to install to?

Tags: 14.04

I have Windows 7 Ultimate and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu. Every time I try to install it, though, I get to the 4th screen that says "Installation type" on the top, and it has the white box where you choose the partition but it is blank. There is a drop down box on the bottom but it only has /dev/sda. Also, I was never prompted with a screen asking whether to remove Windows, dual boot or "something else". There are the 3 buttons under the partition box that say +, -, and change. I tried clicking change, but nothing happened, just my hard drive spinning for a second. Also, I have tried different discs with different .iso files and they did the same thing. I have to hard reset my computer to reboot. Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/317535/what-should-i-do-at-installation-type-step-in-the-ubuntu-installation

Answer (score 0):

It is completely normal for the partition manager to take a little time. You should not bother about that. Leave it for few minutes.

To check installation media for errors, run an integrity check on the installation media you are using. This can be done using the first screen that appears when booting from that media.

Comment: I chose check disc for defects and after a while it just sat on a black screen for 15 minutes doing nothing so I hard reset and rebooted from the disc and got a bunch of scrolling text.

Comment: I rebooted again this time I chose install ubuntu. I got to the screen that says installation type and it still didn't show anything.